# data preparation of a large data set in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to do a simple time series visualization of my data that looks like the following:

`1;2;0;"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;";"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0";"11";13.10.2016 10:13:42
2;1;0;"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;";"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0";"1";13.10.2016 10:13:42`

For all I know is that the sensors' data are stored in these two strings full of 0's (not all rows contain exclusively 0's). How would I proceed to create a dataframe with a column for each sensor's date? Or what does allow me to plot the sensor data over time (it's like 25 and 20 sensors).

What I tried is the following:

`data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';')
df = pd.concat([data[[0:3]], data[3].str.split(';', expand=True),data[4].str.split(';', expand=True), data[[-2,-1]]], axis=1)`

However it takes so long that I did not wait for a result of processing 900,000 rows ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use parameter `quoting`:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u'''
1;2;0;"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;";"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0";"11";13.10.2016 10:13:42
2;1;0;"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;";"0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0";"1";13.10.2016 10:13:42
'''
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, header=None)

#temporary diplay 52 columns
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', 52):
    print (df)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  \
0   1   2   0  "0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   2   1   0  "0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

   19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27 28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  \
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  "  "0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  "  "0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

   38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48    49                   50  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0"  "11"  13.10.2016 10:13:42  
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0"   "1"  13.10.2016 10:13:42
```

And then `apply` with [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
#data cleaning
cols = [3, 29, 48, 49]
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"').astype(int))
#remove empty column
df = df.drop(28, axis=1)
#reset columns names
df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.columns))
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', 52):
    print (df)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  \
0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

   19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  \
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

   38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48                   49  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  11  13.10.2016 10:13:42  
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1  13.10.2016 10:13:42
```

Comment: with the complete file I got this error message but this should be about the quality of the data then I guess: CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 50 fields in line 33595, saw 51

Comment: Hmmm, is possible omit this line?

Comment: Solution is add `error_bad_lines=False`, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#handling-bad-lines)

Comment: I guess the trick is the quoting param, no? Thanks a lot for the very quick reply!!

Comment: Exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I found out that the problem lies in parsing the file because when I paste in the mentioned lines in the StringIO param it works perfectly fine. Do you know how to solve this problem? (Error now: CParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 51 and found 50)

Comment: parameter `error_bad_lines=False` does not work? [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#handling-bad-lines)

Comment: But I believe problematic data parsing is not easy, because data depending :(

Comment: One idea, is possible add parameter `nrows=10000` (change it by your data) to `read_csv` and find problematic rows where solution failed?

Comment: wiat, wait, it filter only first N rows, not all data... Try increase number.

Comment: well, sorry I was reading the test file with the temp string saved in a file. anyways it is interesting that this worked but the real data file not although I copied the temp string from the real data file